# Android custom animation when calling activity outside of application?

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I know how to use overridePendingTranition to change the animation between activities inside of my own application. My question is how can I get the same result when sending an intent to open a Youtube video for example. It will work correctly but because the Youtube application is not a translucent theme I see a black screen immediately and then the content slide in using my animation. Is there anyway to control the animation starting that activity as well as the animation that will run when the user clicks back to come back to your application?

Thanks